# Is sshd_config TPCKeepAlive still using unencrypted channel and therefore vulnerable

Tags: ssh, security, tcp, sshd

This [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=831372) from 2008 in ubuntuforums recommends disabling `TCPKeepAlive`

> Disable TCP KeepAlive messages. These messages are spoofable and are sent outside of the encrypted channel, and ClientAliveInterval is an encrypted, unspoofable (that I know of) alternative, so I see no reason to use TCPKeepAlive.

Is that still the case? Is it secure to use `TCPKeepAlive` or is it better to use `ClientAliveInterval`?

I am asking this because digitalocean uses `TCPKeepAlive` by default and if there is vulnerability wouldn't they stop using it?

Comment: Even if someone "hack" TCP connection, it shouldn't raise it up to SSH connection, because SSH messages should be protected by HMAC (and will be basically rejected by receiver if incorrect HMAC is sent), but I'm not crypto specialist, so this is just an _opinion_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't believe everything you read on the Internet. :) There is no security problem with enabling `TCPKeepAlive`.  There never was any such problem.  The meaning of the warning in the `sshd_config(5)` manual is that you shouldn't rely on `TCPKeepAlive` **alone**, since an attacker can spoof it to fool the server into thinking a connection is still alive when it actually isn't.  Rather, you should use `TCPKeepAlive` **together with** `ClientAliveInterval`.

You can use `ClientAliveInterval` without `TCPKeepAlive`, but in the vast majority of cases disabling `TCPKeepAlive` doesn't accomplish any useful purpose.  The only effect is that `ssh` connections that are idle for more than the TCP timeout on your machine (2 hours by default on Linux) will get closed.  That's all there is to it.